# Dropwizard: integration of Google Guice

Tags: maven, guice, dropwizard, guice-3

I try to use dependency injection in DropWizard with Google Guice but I have a lot of problems. So I programmed a simple code like below to find the main problem. The errors are in the class Test, line :testservice.Result (10,10,10). 
    - Syntax error on token "(", { expected after this token
    - Syntax error on tokens, ConstructorHeaderName expected 
     instead
    - Syntax error on token "Result", invalid AnnotationName

why I can't use the object testservice ?

Thanks for your help.

```
package dropwizard.GoogleGuiiice;
import io.dropwizard.Application;
import io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap;
import io.dropwizard.setup.Environment;

public class GoogleGuiiiceApplication extends Application<GoogleGuiiiceConfiguration> {
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    new GoogleGuiiiceApplication().run(args);
}
@Override
public String getName() {
    return "GoogleGuiiice";
}
@Override
public void initialize(final Bootstrap<GoogleGuiiiceConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    // TODO: application initialization
}
@Override
public void run(final GoogleGuiiiceConfiguration configuration,
                final Environment environment) {
    // TODO: implement application
    environment.jersey().register(new Test ());
}
```

}

```
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;

public class Test {
Injector guice=Guice.createInjector(new OperationModule());
TestService testservice=guice.getInstance(TestService.class);   
testservice.Result (10,10,10);
```

}

```
public interface Operation {
int getResult(int a, int b);
```

}

```
public class Somme implements Operation{
@Override
public int getResult(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}
```

}

```
public class OperationModule extends com.google.inject.AbstractModule{
@Override
protected void configure(){
    bind(Operation.class).to(Somme.class);
}
```

}

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
public class TestService {
@Inject
Operation Op;

@GET
@Path("{a}/{b}")
public int Result (int c, @PathParam(value="a")int a, @PathParam(value="b")int b){
    int SommeFinale=c + Op.getResult(a,b);
    return SommeFinale;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what you are actually attempting to do here but to answer your question from a purely Java perspective the syntax error is simply because you are not allowed to execute arbitrary statements at that point in your code.

If you really do wish to execute that statement at that point then you either need to wrap it in curly braces so that it is in an initializer block but this would likely be pointless given the implementation as the result is thrown away

```
{
  testService.Result(10,10,10);
}
```

or you need to assign the result to a field

```
int useMe = testService.Result(10,10,10);
```

Other options are that you could execute the statement in a constructor or method of the Test class.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this tutorial can help.
[Dropwizard and Guice Integration](http://Dropwizard%20and%20Guice%20Integration)